# Excluding column from T-SQL RowVersion update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database table in SQL Server that I am using T-SQL's `RowVersion` to record a `GenerationNumber` and detect have any records changed. This paradigm has worked successfully for my application, but now I want to add a column that does not increment the `RowVersion` column on `UPDATE`.

Is there any way of excluding a column from the `RowVersion` increment? Or should I change the datatype of `RowVersion` to a `datetime` and handle it myself in a trigger?

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome

Comment: You can't do that. It is special column and it does exactly what is supposed to. If you have such functionality I would suggest to add another column instead of changing datatype. Anyway, any particular reason why do you want to have such behavior?

Answer (score 2):

If you currently have a table `T` - rename it as something like `T_Tracked` and introduce a second table `T_Untracked` that has a FK back to the first table.

Then introduce a view, `T`, that joins these tables together. Your application continues to reference `T`. You then put your "trigger-writing" hat on and write appropriate triggers on this view to ensure that both tables are populated during an `insert`, both are deleted from during `delete` and only the applicable tables are updated during an `update`.

That way it appears to still be a `rowversion` column but updates that only affect `T_Untracked` will not cause it to be changed.